Induced adjoint operator norms seem inconsistent for some cases of $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$
Consider a matrix $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$ and scalars $p,q \in [1, \infty]$. Denote the $\ell_p^m \rightarrow \ell_q^n$ induced operator norm of $M$ by $\|M\|_{p,q}$. For the norm of the adjoint operator of $M$, denoted by $M^*$, we have the following formula
\begin{equation*}
    \|M^*\|_{p', q'} = \|M\|_{p, q},
\end{equation*}
where the scalars $p'$ and $q'$ are Hölder's conjugate to $p$ and $q$, respectively. Which means that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p'} = \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{q'} = 1$. First question: Why do the following equalities not hold considering this is all finite dimensional?
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        1) \quad \|M\|_{1, \infty} &= \|M^*\|_{\infty, 1}\\
        2) \quad \|M\|_{\infty, 2} &= \|M^*\|_{1, 2}\\
        3) \quad \|M\|_{2, \infty} &= \|M^*\|_{2, 1}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Second question: Why does the following equality hold?
\begin{equation*}
    4) \quad \|M\|_{1,1} = \|M^*\|_{\infty, \infty}
\end{equation*}
Sources: Wikipedia Operator norm, Rohn 1999, Barak 2009

The correct formula should be $\lVert M^\ast\rVert_{q',p'}=\lVert M\rVert_{p,q}$.

Of course, thank you!
